# XAMPP control panel no errors but MySQL wont open

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am currently learning PHP and I use XAMPP for my MySQL. This was supposed to be my 2nd code-along project when I encountered a problem. There are no problems in the XAMPP control panel but when I open MySQL, the try catch method that I created in index.php for my router captured the error. I also tried to change the port of MySQL's default port and Apache's 80 to 8080 in config -> service and port settings, but still no changes, the same as changing the port in my.ini. The router I created is not for production and it is for learning purposes only to better understand it.

Any solution will help! Thank you!

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\View;

session_start();

define('STORAGE_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../storage');
define('VIEW_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../views');

try {
    $router = new App\Exceptions\Router();

    $router
        ->get('/', [App\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])
        ->post('/upload', [App\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'upload'])
        ->get('/invoices', [App\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'index'])
        ->get('/invoices/create', [App\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'create'])
        ->post('/invoices/create', [App\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'store']);

    echo $router->resolve($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));

} catch (\App\Exceptions\RouteNotFoundException $e) {
    // header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
    http_response_code(404);
 echo View::make('error/404');
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says it can't find the route for `phpmyadmin`. Do you have it installed?

Comment: Your router _should_ not be involved in this in the first place, XAMPP comes with phpMyAdmin available under the `/phpmyadmin` path already. You did not tell us how you set up the connection between the web server and your router, but is sounds like you might have made your router process _every_ request, regardless of whether it matches an existing file/folder, or not ...?

Comment: I didn't. I only clicked the admin button for MySQL in the XAMPP control panel thinking it magically worked.

Comment: @CBroe I think this is the answer I am looking for. The router I created is for learning purposes only and I am just coding along. It has no exception for phpmyadmin and to be honest, I don't know how to configure it. But before I posted this problem, Im already speculating that the router might caused this problem.

Comment: This isn't about that PHP code though; You must have done _something_, to make your webserver _invoke_ that code, for arbitrary requests. And that is the part where it goes wrong. Usually this gets configured in a way, that the web server itself will respond to all requests that match onto an existing folder or file in the "usual" way, and _not_ pass those requests to your router script.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't do anything other than create a 2nd project. For the first project that I abandoned, I cut it from htdocs, saved it somewhere, and created a new folder for my 2nd project. Aside from that, I also configured the vhost for the document root and server name and edit the host file to access the server name I created. I did not touched anything except the things that I mentioned.

Comment: But that error text your screenshots shows, with the :( at the end - that is from your own 404 template, correct? (Just to make sure, that my analysis of the problem so far is actually correct.) I can't tell you what you might have done in your setup, to get this behavior. If you already had an earlier project running, maybe there's leftover URL rewrite code somewhere.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I created that 404 template. Do you have in mind what l potentially missed configuring before proceeding with this project? Do you have a link that I can study if it its $router is causing the problem? Sorry if I'm asking too much. I don't have a mentor or colleagues as study buddies. I'm on a self-taught route.

Comment: _"if it its $router is causing the problem?"_ - as I already said: No, rather not. The request for a physically existing directory (and `phpmyadmin` _does_ is exist in your document root that `localhost` points to, correct?) _should not_ get passed to your router script in the first place.

Comment: I suppose the router relies on .htaccess ? (My guess)

Comment: @KenLee I dont have .htaccess. It was already coded in vhost to gain full access.

Comment: In that case please edit your vhost to exclude phpmyadmin in the routing

Comment: @KenLee Can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using RewriteRule to build your routing in vhost config file, then please add the following line before other redirect rule(s) so that the system will exclude phpmyadmin directory:

```
RewriteRule ^(phpmyadmin)($|/) - [L]
```

Hence, in case your current vhost is like this:

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1
```

then, change it to :

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(phpmyadmin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1
```